# WooCommerce Shipping Zone for Dubai Areas

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am currently working with WooCommerce and facing a challenge. I need to create shipping zones to encompass all areas within Dubai, but it appears that Dubai areas do not have specific postal codes.

I would greatly appreciate your insights and guidance on how to establish shipping zones that cover all Dubai areas despite the absence of postal codes for these regions.

I have some examples :-

**Dubai Area**                   **Min Order**                 **Delivery Charge**

Al barsha 1                         80.00                                     10.00

Al Barsha 2                         80.00                                     10.00

Al Barsha 3                         80.00                                     10.00

Abu hail                                80.00                                     7.00

Academic City                   25.00                                      5.00

Airport Free zone              80.00                                    7.00

Al Aweer                             80.00                                    5.00

Al badaa                              80.00                                     7.00

Al baraha                             80.00                                     7.00

so on...............................

Thank you for your valuable assistance!

I'm currently working with WooCommerce and facing a challenge regarding the creation of shipping zones. When configuring shipping zones, I would like to include all areas within Dubai in the list. However, I've noticed that besides the United Arab Emirates, Dubai is not listed, and there are no specific areas available.

I would greatly appreciate your guidance on how to properly set up shipping zones to cover all areas within Dubai, considering this issue.

Comment: There are not really other work-around, for your case, in WooCommerce, than [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63293197/how-to-add-new-states-for-a-country-to-woocommerce/63293545#63293545). Or you can search for shipping plugins that handle cites or/and custom areas.